# Bootstrap slide box

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello i have found a nice javascript effect of box in
[link 1](https://www.ultimatebeaver.com/modules/slide-box/) 
[link 2](https://jdfserwis.pl/cennik/)

But it's for wordpress only.

Is it possible to make same slide box with Bootstrap and javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple example of recreating the slide down effect on the links you posted. It can be done fairly easily just using html and css.

```
<div tabindex="1" class="mainbox">
  <h1>
    This is a box with hidden content
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  <h2>
    I am no longer hidden
  </h2>
</div>
```

```
div {
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  background:#3c3c3c;
  color:black;
}
.mainbox {
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.mainbox:hover {
  outline:none;
}
.hidden {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0.75;
  -webkit-transition:top 1s;
  -moz-transition:top 1s;
}
.mainbox:hover + .hidden {
  top:200px;
  -webkit-transition:top 1s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tz3vjLg7/

Answer (score 0):

Try this; with this approach you can move the main container to any place you want, add margins, paddings, etc to `main-container` without having to also re position the sliding panels inside

```css
.main-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.main-panel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  z-index: 1
}

.slide-panel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main-container:hover .slide-panel {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(150px)
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="main-panel"></div>
  <div class="slide-panel">Slide Panel</div>
</div>
```